# Combo box displays numeric values as squares

Tags: combobox, vb6

I have a simple combo box that I've prepopulated with numeric values (eg. 1, 2, 3, etc.).  When I run my app and drop-down the list, all I see is little squares instead of numbers.

Is this some kind of character set issue?

This [sample code](http://www.capablesoftware.com.au/images/ComboBoxSample.zip) creates the effect in both the IDE and when run.

Comment: Text values work fine.  Also, I see the squares in the IDE as well as when I run the app.

Comment: In what language are you typing these numeric characters?

Comment: Have you put quotes around the numbers?

Comment: The language is US English.  I tried putting quotes around.  That changes the entries to text entries, and they start appearing correctly - with the quotes around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that adding the combobox list entries using the IDE is the cause of the problem.  So, for example, in the IDE go to the Properties tab, click on the (List) property, and key the entries (eg 1 followed by CTRL-ENTER followed by 2 followed by CTRL-ENTER, etc).  This produces the defective 'square boxes effect'.

If you add the entries to the list programmatically, there is no problem.

Comment: I've also discovered that the problem only manifests for single digit numerical values (eg '1' appears as a square box, but '13' appears correctly).

Comment: Is this due to the regional settings of your PC, forcing the IDE to run the same way? When I view your form on a US English PC, the combo box entries show up in the IDE as BLANKS in the properties window.

Answer (score 1):

Any controls that you drop on a form by default use the same font properties as the form itself.  Check the form's font setting.  You will need to also make any corresponding changes to any controls already existing on the form, but once you set the font on the form itself, any future controls drawn on the form will use the font you defined.

If the font of the form itself is incorrect when you add a new form, then you need to look at the settings of the IDE itself for its default font settings.

Comment: The font for the form (and the control) is MS Sans Serif.  Its used extensively throughout the app, and no other forms or controls are experiencing the problem. Note that it only affects numerical values in the dropdown combobox.  Text values appear correctly.

Comment: It almost has to be some kind of regional setting.  Is this one of the standard combobox controls or a third-party control?  Some of the more sophisticated third-party controls have more than one font setting.

Comment: I thought so too.  Its the standard ComboBox from VB6.  I'm seeing the behaviour at a customer site as well as my own PC.  I use v6.0.97.82 of MSVBVM60.dll on my PC.  Not sure about the client site PC.

Comment: Check that... its v6.0.98.15.

Comment: Please add the code to your original post where you're pre-populating the combo.  Longshot, but perhaps you're doing chr(value+x) or something and it might be unicode?  Are you adding the items as cstr()?  format()?

Comment: I just populated it using the IDE.  In the properties tab, I click on the (List) property and add the values there.

Comment: Follow up... if I add the entries programmatically, everything is fine.  I'll repost this as an answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All the same happens to me in Windows 11. Numbers like 1, 2, 3... shows like square (in IDE after I populated, closed List and reopened it again), but 10, 11, 12 etc appears ok. Therefore I used space & 1, space & 2 instead of 1, 2, then use Val() function to get correct values (you may use also select case Listbox.index or similar. Do not understand why this has to be so, but this is life..